# How do I change the state of an instance of a component when using DeviceEventEmitter in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm connecting two bluetooth sensors to my React Native app (Android). When a sensor connects, it fires a deviceConnect event that I am listening for in my React Native code using a `DeviceEventEmitter` listener. I have a `Sensor` component that I'm using to display the state of each sensor but whenever the listener fires to update the `isConnected` state of a `Sensor` instance (e.g. sensor 1 connects) it's updating the state in both `Sensor`s i.e. it's showing the connected state to be true for both sensors rather than just the connected one. A cut down version of my code is below.

```
class Sensor extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
         sensorAddress: null,
         sensorIsConnected:false,
         sensorIsDiscovering: false,
         sensorBattery:0
       };
     }

    componentWillUnmount(){
      DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener('deviceConnect', (message) => console.log(message))
    }

     componentDidMount(){
       DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
         'deviceConnect',
         (data) => {
           this.setState({sensorIsConnected: true})
           console.log("Connected" + JSON.stringify(data))
         }
       );
     }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>CONNECTED EQUALS {this.state.sensorIsConnected}</Text>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

class TwoSensors extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Sensor 1</Text>
        <Sensor key="sensor1"/>
        <Text>Sensor 2</Text>
        <Sensor key="sensor2"/>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I think this is related to how the `DeviceEventEmitter` is bound but I can't for the life of me work out what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `deviceConnect` callback returns the device name so I can actually make the changes below and it works fine. All I'm doing is passing in the `sensorName` as a prop to each Sensor component (in the real app it's coming from Apollo Client) and then, in the `deviceConnect` listener, checking if the name of the sensor returned in the callback matches the `sensorName` prop.

```
  class Sensor extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
           sensorAddress: null,
           sensorIsConnected:false,
           sensorIsDiscovering: false,
           sensorBattery:0
         };
       }

      componentWillUnmount(){
        DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener('deviceConnect', (message) => console.log(message))
      }

       componentDidMount(){
         DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
           'deviceConnect',
           (data) => {
             if (this.props.sensorName == data.name) {
                this.setState({sensorIsConnected: true})
                console.log("Connected" + JSON.stringify(data))
             }
           }
         );
       }

    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>CONNECTED EQUALS {this.state.sensorIsConnected}</Text>
      </View>
      );
    }
  }

  class TwoSensors extends React.Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Sensor 1</Text>
          <Sensor key="sensor1" sensorName="sensor1"/>
          <Text>Sensor 2</Text>
          <Sensor key="sensor2" sensorName="sensor2"/>
      </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`DeviceEventEmitter` registration is a global event！The two different sensor components should have different behavior，so you'd better give up using it.

According to my reasoning, you want to control two sensors in the TwoSensors components.You can declare some `props` in the sensor component.You can using different behavior is given like `<Sensor key="sensor1" onDeviceConnect={() => { //do something1 }}/><Sensor key="sensor2" onDeviceConnect={() => { //do something2 }}/>`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Knowing it was a global event helped me think it over and I have a simple working solution (see posted answer)